# JEditorPane is not converting html to text properly when copied from Microsoft word or other content from online

Tags: java, html, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I am trying to convert html to text using JEditorPane. It is not converting html to text properly and text has still html tags like font and color. Below is the code that I have used.

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane("text/html", html);
((HTMLDocument)jep.getDocument()).setPreservesUnknownTags(false);
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)jep.getDocument();
htmlDoc.setPreservesUnknownTags(false);
System.out.println(htmlDoc.getText(0, htmlDoc.getLength()));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane("text/html", html);
String plainText = pane.getDocument().getText(0, pane.getDocument().getLength()); 
System.out.println(plainText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate html, you might be interested in using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

You might especially be interested in the `text` method:

```
Gets the combined text of this element and all its children. 

//example
return Jsoup.parse("<p>testing <span>jsoup</span></p>").text();
//returns "testing jsoup"
```